# png not appearing, Firefox adding non-existent class, Chrome adding inline styles

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, firefox

http://www.criminalwatch.com/default.asp

The img in top right of the skyscraper banner does not appear in Firefox and Chrome, but appears in IE 10.  Here  is the img source code:

```
<img src="/inc/Intelius/120X600/0035.png" alt="People Search" width="116" height="91"/>
```

Inspecting the element in Firefox 25 reveals this non-existent class being inserted:

```
<img class="qemirobcotnnalosqccu" width="116" height="91" alt="People Search" src="/inc/Intelius/120X600/0035.png"></img>
```

In Chrome 31, the following disasbling styles are inserted:

```
<img src="/inc/Intelius/120X600/0035.png" alt="People Search" width="0" height="0" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 116px 91px;">
```

Comment: you sure you don't just have some kind of generic js selector hiding this?

Comment: works fine to me ... on chrome and firefox

Comment: It works on my machine. (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) Do you have ad-blocking active by any chance?

Comment: On my machine it does not appear. It had `width="0"` `height="0"` and `display: none;`

Comment: Sounds like ad blocking software of some kind.

Comment: I disabled Ads Removal extension in Chrome & Firefox.  png appeared.